# Github Actions worklfow logs are not expandable anymore

Tags: github-actions, github-actions-runners, github-ci, github-actions-workflows

Out of the blue, I cannot see the logs for my github action workflow job steps, I was able to view these before but today without any changes, I can't expand and see the logs for the steps of a job. Does anyone know what could be the issue here and how to fix it?
Attached a screenshot of the run where the logs exist and another where they don't

Logs available :
[image]

Logs missing: [image]